# Find the duplicate field name records present inside the nested array object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, count, duplicates, aggregate

My collection :

```js
[
  {
    "Empname": "Doug",
    "Group": [
      {
        "Category": [
          {
            "Categoryid": 123,
            "Categoryname": "science"
          },
          {
            "Categoryid": 233,
            "Categoryname": "Maths"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Empname": "stark",
    "Group": [
      {
        "Category": [
          {
            "Categoryid": 123,
            "Categoryname": "science"
          },
          {
            "Categoryid": 144,
            "Categoryname": "language "
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to display the following output
Here categoryid 123 and categoryname science is present twice.I want to display this duplicate like

```js
{"categoryname":"science","count":2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to perform `$unwind` twice to unwind the nested arrays and perform `$group` on the Category fields.

Below query is what you are looking for

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Group"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Group.Category"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "Categoryid": "$Group.Category.Categoryid",
        "Categoryname": "$Group.Category.Categoryname",
        
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4HJP2t-67o_)

**Edit: Improving with [@Takis_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4882692/takis) suggestion**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Group"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Group.Category"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "Categoryid": "$Group.Category.Categoryid",
        "Categoryname": "$Group.Category.Categoryname",
        
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "count": {
        "$gt": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "Categoryname": "$_id.Categoryname",
      "count": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TVhzNNfwN7Z)

Comment: with 1-2 simple stages more to be [like the expected output](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TVhzNNfwN7Z)

Comment: @Takis_ thanks for the suggestion, I have updated the answer.